# HOUR_OF_DAY in date showing 12 hr time

Tags: java, swing, calendar, simpledateformat, jspinner

I am trying to display time in this format hh:mm in jsinner control

But I am getting 12 hrs time not 24 hrs

Here is my code

Where am I wrong

```
Date date = new Date();
SpinnerDateModel sm = new SpinnerDateModel(date, null, null, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
arr_time.setModel(sm);
JSpinner.DateEditor ar = new JSpinner.DateEditor(arr_time, "hh:mm");
arr_time.setEditor(ar);
```

Pls guide

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
JSpinner.DateEditor ar = new JSpinner.DateEditor(arr_time, "HH:mm");
```

`hh` indicates 12 hour format.
`HH` indicates 24 hour format

Comment: always welcome. Accept the answer once you workout with the same.